# Find the "direction" of a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location, shortest-path, origin-destination

I have a set of transportation analysis zones, and a set of shorted path polyline features connecting the centroids of each zone.  There are two line features between each zone, one for each direction.  Each line feature has an attribute, the travel demand between the origin and destination zone. The demand is not necessarily symmetrical.

I am trying to capture the total demand along "corridors".  Each corridor is a buffered zone around the line feature connecting two zones.  The buffer is used to select by location all other line features (connecting zones) that fall within the buffer.

I am now trying to sort out the demand by direction. I would like to select all line features whose destination zone is closer than its source zone to the corridor destination.

I am using Model Builder in ArcMap 10.2.2.  I can successfully select all line features within the buffered corridor and dissolve the demand, however, I am having difficulty sorting by direction.  I have tried several ideas, but have not found a working solution.  Does anybody have advice for how to approach the problem?

--
Edit:
I am currently using mock data, but I have 5 "census tracts", with an 11 digit GEOID ending with 1-5.  Each path has a start and end zone, with a separate line feature representing the path in each direction.  "Est" is the demand from origin to destination (circa 2010 CCTP commuter flows).
[image]

Comment: Could you please update your question with picture

Comment: Hi Felix, I have added an image illustrating my current attempt.  I am open to possibly using a different method if it might work better.

Comment: What do you mean by "direction" and how does one sort by it?

Comment: Looking at the above, the feature from 3 to 2 is highlighted.  I want to distinguish this from 2 to 3.

For instance, I would like to collect all paths from 5 to 1.  This would include "5-1, 5-4 ,4-1 ,5-4, 3-1, etc" but not the opposite features (1-3, 1-4, 4-5, 1-5, etc).

Comment: So it is like a braided river and you'd like to find a shortest/fastest single route from any node to destination?

Comment: Maybe?  I already have the shortest path from node to node...

-Say there is a center city, and a several suburbs due east.  The outer suburb might be purely residential, and the center city purely commercial, with a gradient in between.  

From the outer suburb, everyone travels west in the morning.  Some will stop one zone over, some two over, etc, up to the center city.  From the second zone, the same repeats.  From third, some demand will trickle back east towards the second, because it will have some commercial activity.

I am trying to capture all demand heading west towards the city.

Comment: I am sure this is a fairly standard problem.  I am just not certain what it is called, because it is somewhat cumbersome to describe, and thus difficult to look up strategies for solving.

Comment: If you have from and to node names attached to you links, it is simply a total of demand for the links, where to_node=target. Thus split your name in two values to populate fields to store those names

Comment: It is more of a fuzzy search, because the arcs are not well defined.  The shortest path between the outer zones apart might not perfectly match the paths in and out of the intermediate zones.  It is perhaps an somewhat like snapping adjacent paths together within the search radius.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up finding a solution, not an elegant one, but a working one.

Each path had an origin and destination zone.  I added the x and y coordinates to for each zone as attributes to the line feature, and then calculated the respective distances to the x and y coordinates of the corridor destination zone.